# Fullfillment error "Platform "GOOGLE_HANGOUTS' not supported." when using inline editor to fulfill my code after hitting an API

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am hitting an API and returning required values to a chat-bot. Though I am getting response in Dialogflow's Default Response Simulator but for the same code I am not getting any response in Hangout chat API (I have integrated Dialogflow with Hangout chat).

```
function func_name(agent){
   const abcd = agent.parameters.abcd;
   agent.add(`Below are the products related to ${abcd}`);
   return axios.get(`https://*********************/****/${abcd}`)
      .then((result)=>{
         result.data.map(abcdObj => {
            agent.add(JSON.stringify(abcdObj.name+"~"+abcdObj.key));
   });
});
```

and the error message what I am receiving is:

```
Error: Platform 'GOOGLE_HANGOUTS' not supported. 
Function execution took 12 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here I got solution for the issue by google. You will have to upgrade the version of dependencies , dialogflow version to 0.7.0 and dialogflow-fulfillment to 0.6.1 in package.json of your fulfillment code and if your bot still doesn't work try to create new bot with same functionality. It will help for sure.